# Why is my UWP app laggy (only) under Windows 11?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-11

Since several years I have an UWP app (card game) in the Microsoft Store. It is well tested and runs fluidly on Windows 10 even on an i5 CPU with only onboard graphics. The app UI is built with XAML and the program code is written in C++. Last week I bought a brand new Lenovo ThinkBook 16p laptop with AMD Ryzen 5800H CPU and Windows 11 Pro installed. GPU's are AMD Radeon and NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3060.

To my bad surprise on this machine all animations of my app (made of XAML storyboards) are extremly laggy and even the sound output is never in time. I tested with both GPU's and all power options, drivers and Win11 are updated.

Any ideas what could cause these issues?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tested with intel process computer, it may has a few problem for  AMD Ryzen cpu within Windows 11 os.

Comment: Yes, one of my testers reported to me that it is running fine on his Win11 with Intel CPU. Can't believe that XAML is broken on AMD, but when Win11 was brand new there were some AMD related issues - I'm confused.

Comment: Yep,  the better way is report it in WInUi github or send feedback with windows feedback hub app.

Comment: It turned out that the Realtek audio driver on my new Lenovo ThinkBook 16p laptop with AMD Ryzen 5800H CPU and Windows 11 Pro installed is causing the described issues. If I deactivate it in the Windows settings then all XAML based animations run fine at normal speed. Application Timeline profiling shows that, altough all audio is directly packed inside the UWP app, the Realtek audio driver loads those (WAV) far to slow. The driver is from August 2021 but no newer version is available for the Lenovo 16p AMD with Windows 11.

Comment: Please go ahead convert above comment as answer for this thread and mark yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that the Realtek audio driver on my new Lenovo ThinkBook 16p laptop with AMD Ryzen 5800H CPU and Windows 11 Pro installed is causing the described issues. If I deactivate it in the Windows settings then all XAML based animations run fine at normal speed. Application Timeline profiling shows that, although all audio is directly packed inside the UWP app, the Realtek audio driver loads those (WAV) far to slow. The driver is from August 2021 but no newer version is available for the Lenovo 16p AMD with Windows 11.

If suitable, preloading audio assets is one way to fix the described problem.